# Can I answer a question in the simple past with present perfect?

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-perfect

Can a question in the simple past be answered with present perfect? For instance, if someone said

> I bought some milk five hours ago."

could I answer

> Where have you put it?

I know I can use the simple past here, but could I use the present perfect here as well if I'm interested in where the milk is now?

Comment: Yes............................ (And in British English the present perfect might be the preferred form.)

Comment: But using the perfect present doesn't stress where it is now. If you want to do that, use the simple present, *where is it?*

Comment: @Clare I'd say present perfect stresses the need to know the present whereabouts equally, without sounding as abrupt as the present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interplay of tenses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414817/interplay-of-tenses)

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can. Very keen of you to notice the momemtary feeling of non-sequitur that results as we are so used to parroting the question in the answer. People also sometimes use that technique as a subtle way to correct another's grammar, as I am sure you have also noticed!